# How to dump a string-like python object into simple yaml without any tags?

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

Let's say a simple class:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '"{}"'.format(self.value)
```

I just want to dump instance object of this class into simple yaml. For example, `MyString("abc")` to `"abc"` in yaml.

I tried this:

```
# Define a custom YAML representation for the MyString class
def mystring_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('!qs', str(data))

yaml.add_representer(MyString, mystring_representer)
```

But `represent_scalar()` method needs `tag`, and this tag will be in result yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag will *not* be in the YAML if it's the default tag.

```py
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

def mystring_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_SCALAR_TAG, str(data))

yaml.add_representer(MyString, mystring_representer)
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem with methods that are not found in the official documentation